# Ease of access window auto arrange and 2nd monitor

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, hotkeys

I have two monitors; I frequently shift open windows between them. I love that Windows 8.1 has built in hotkey functionality to do this (Windows key + left or right arrow), but I hate the auto arrange/resize that occurs when a window is dragged near a screen edge. After disabling auto arrange, I find the winkey+arrow function no longer works!
How might one go about re-enabling the hotkey function?

Comment: This is the 3rd forum I've asked with 0 response.  Am I missing something?